# Failed to generate Signed APK with error Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, androidx

Hi I have this problem when generating signed APK.
I followed all the steps with passwords till the end and there was no issue. After a while, the system showed below error:

C:/xxx/xxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/13198b4331ddc46ae8fed89fb101cb63/transformed/jetified-core-ktx-1.10.1-api.jar!/META-INF/core-ktx_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

I have below in the Gradle (global)

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
  
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

    }
}

I m using Chipmunk version
```

In this App, I did have some kotlin synthetic as I am not using Ktx: 1.8.0 ( I am using 1.7.10).

Can you please help what I need to do. Thanks